# How to select distinct records with where conditions without using sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with the following schema

```
(Id(int PK),EmployeeId(int),DepartmentId(int),IsSelfAccessToDepartment(bit))
```

this table can contain the following entries

```
(1,101,21,1)
(2,101,22,0)
(3,102,21,1)
(4,103,21,1)
(5,103,22,0)
```

I want to retrieve only those employee Ids where the IsSelfAccessToDepartment=1 i.e. if the same employee Id has another entry where IsSelfAccessToDepartment=0 in that case this row should not be retrieved.

The problem is I want to retrieve this information without using any sub queries and joins cause it will create performance issues as this table will be having millions of entries.

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: select * from table_name where IsSelfAccessToDepartment=1;

Comment: @JYoThI yes, but he says he wants only employees who have only one row for their id, with that value of 1. i.e. he doesnt want to ever see employees who have 2 rows

Comment: This is a basic SQL query where condition. Why would you even consider using subqueries? What have you tried as well?

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos he wants a resultset containing only "102"; he doesnt want rows returned at all for "101" and "103"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Min function should be utilized to filter out all employees that had entry with 0.
Max function should be utilized also to limit entries to not higher than 1.

```
SELECT employeeID, MIN(IsSelfAccessToDepartment) FROM test2 GROUP BY employeeID
HAVING MIN(isSelfAccessToDepartment) = 1;
```

Finally:

- count is not necessary as this is not a requirement requested by the OP
- the code `AND  MAX(isSelfAccessToDepartment) = 1` could be added if `IsSelfAccessToDepartment` was not a bit. However, as it is a bit, the two available values are zero and one (thanks @Caius for this point in the comments).

Additionally, there are also other creative solutions (but inefficient), for example:

```
SELECT employeeID FROM test2 GROUP BY employeeID
HAVING SUM(isSelfAccessToDepartment) = COUNT(isSelfAccessToDepartment);
```

This one assumes isSelfAccessToDepartment can be zero or 1. If no zero entries exist, the sum will be the same as the count.

Comment: And this is what sucks about stack overflow; you edit your answer to plagiarise mine, and you get the points for it.. (Especially galling seeing as at the start you couldn't even see how to answer the question)

Comment: @Caius Jard your initial answer was wrong. My Answer was more correct. Check the editing proof here: http://i.prntscr.com/DEoUK2dVTjmJpjbjDpACMA.png . You used a MAX instead of MIN. Revisions: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45412283/revisions AND https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45412248/revisions

Comment: I used count and max, which wasn't wrong in the context of the question, but I later revised that to min and max because of the unspecified example of 3 rows with which COUNT(*) would cause an error. You used min only.. You then edited your answer to clone mine, after I commented on your answer! Not much point trying to wriggle out of it - your first answer was fine btw - the MAX is redundant for a BIT datatype ;) so you really could have left your answer alone, instead of copying someone else's

Comment: COUNT(*) = 1 isn't wrong in the example given by the OP; he wanted employee records that appeared only once, and not with a 0. In the case where someone appears twice (one with 1 and one with 0) the COUNT/MAX drops those people. I switched to using MIN after considering that there may other scenarios where it causes a problem (3x emps). I accept your claim that MIN is a simpler way of achieving the same goal and I even initially praised your solution for using only MIN. Not quite sure why,shortly after i did,you decided that my MIN/MAX answer was the one for you but hey;you know what you stole

Comment: Quit it with the "proper solution" waffle. There is always more than one way to skin a cat. The logic of count/max is sound: "there is only one employee and their max value is 1" works to ensure only employees with one row and value of 1. Could have used pretty much any aggregate function (sum, avg etc.. they all work if there is only one row thanks to count). That's all the OP asked for and it's the part you couldn't understand til I explained it to you.. All this periphery discussion is surrounding an imaginary situation that may not even exist

Comment: Quoted from question: "i.e. if the same employee Id has another entry where IsSelfAccessToDepartment=0 in that case this row should not be retrieved.". This also means, if employee ID has many entries and all entries have IsSelfAccessToDepartment=1, this employeeID should be retrieved. So count(*) = 1 is WRONG and would fail if there was one more data entry: `(6,102,22,1)`. Nowhere does it say that IsSelfAccessToDepartment can only be true/false for only one time per employee.

Comment: I'm pleased to see you're still taking my advice and improving your answer based on it. Seems we make a good team; let me know when you're next stuck on understanding a question and I'll help you out so you can take the credit :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for MySQL or SQLServer:

```
SELECT employeeID FROM table GROUP BY employeeID
HAVING MIN(IsSelfAccessToDepartment) = 1 AND MAX(IsSelfAccessToDepartment) = 1
```

That gets you the employee id only; you can add the department ID in if you need it. Realistically you'll end up joining this info in to get something useful out of it. Plus, it isn't really clear from your example what you expect in cases where an employee has 3 rows

I'd have used ROW_NUMBER() OVER() but MySQL doesn't support it.

Please tag your questions properly to reflect the DB you're using

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS is MySQL

A simple `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` and `COUNT` do this

```
SELECT Id, EmployeeID, DepartmentId, IsSelfAccessToDepartment
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY EmployeeId
HAVING IsSelfAccessToDepartment = 1
AND COUNT(EmployeeID) = 1
```

Output

```
Id  EmployeeID  DepartmentId    IsSelfAccessToDepartment
3   102         21              1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a75b8/1/0

If your DBMS is SQL Server

```
SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id, EmployeeID, MIN(DepartmentId) AS DepartmentId, MIN(IsSelfAccessToDepartment) AS IsSelfAccessToDepartment
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY EmployeeId
HAVING MIN(IsSelfAccessToDepartment) = 1
AND COUNT(EmployeeID) = 1
```

Output

```
Id  EmployeeID  DepartmentId    IsSelfAccessToDepartment
3   102         21              1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b4ef/4/0

Comment: What if there's only one row for employee 104 where `(6,104,21,0)` ?

Comment: As `HAVING IsSelfAccessToDepartment = 1` it wouldn't show, I have updated my SQL Fiddle to show this.

Comment: Hah, I missed that line completely, but then I looked and thought "how does that even work?" - I've no idea what automagical behind the scenes stuff is going on in MySQL (your sql fiddle) but that kind of query will NOT work in SQLServer because several of the columns you select are not mentioned in the group by. It'll give an error like "xxx is invalid in the SELECT / HAVING clause because it's not contained within the group by"

Comment: @CaiusJard included a SQL Server answer also.

Comment: This pattern of querying is dangerous because typically users want a particular row of data based on some criteria, but slinging a load of MINs in there doesn't guarantee that all the visible data comes from the same row..